Read data and write data in bigquery using cloud run app
I want to write a small Python script to run in gcp cloud run. The application will write data from one project and write to another project. Something like insert into SQL statement. Insert into Project1 select * from Project2. What is the best way to do this?

What have you tried?  What research have you done?  What specific areas of function can we assist with?  Sounds like you want to study on how to work with BigQuery in Python and then how to deploy a Python app to Cloud Run.  If you study those, that is likely going to give you guidance.  From there, you can then ask specific/detailed questions on what may be puzzling.
